# java.lang.NullPointerException while getting a cursor in JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, rest, tomcat, nullpointerexception

I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException while accesing a cursor that a procedure returns as an out parameter.

Here are the details:

```
    CallableStatement pstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call PKP_UTIL.GET_VALUE(?,?,?)}");
    pstmt.setObject(1, parameter1);
    pstmt.setObject(2, parameter2);
    pstmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

    pstmt.executeUpdate(); //in this line all goes wrong

    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)pstmt.getObject(3);

    while (rs.next()) {
         System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "\t" + rs.getFloat(2) + "\t" + rs.getDate(3).toString());

    }
```

The details of the application are: 
- Restful WS on Tomcat 6
- Oracle 11g ((11.2.0.2.0)
- JDK 1.7
- JDBC Thin driver

If I try this same code on a desktop application, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

> pstmt.executeUpdate(); //in this line all goes wrong

Not surprising. It should be `execute().` The Javadoc for `executeUpdate()` specifically says the statement must be a 'SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.'

Comment: you're right about the documentation but that's not the problem, I changed it but the exception is still there